# Somehow the DSP library is combining a stereo channel to a mono one, any ideas?

Tags: audio, stm32, adc, dac, stereo

I have a confusing problem that's happening to me, ill explain it to the best of my abilities with code, text, all that good stuff.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have a laptop that uses its **in-line output** into an **ADC**. The **ADC** then goes into my [STM32H7 MCU](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753zi.html). The MCU processes the audio signal using the [CMSIS DSP LIBRARY](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__BiquadCascadeDF1.html). Once done doing the signal processing it shoots the newly filter data into the **DAC** from there the DAC is then connected to my headphones via an **auxiliary cable**.

When I play a music file that has stereo I hear it in both speakers of my headphone. Using this site as reference. [Site I used to check for stereo](https://www.audiocheck.net/audiotests_stereo.php)

**DIAGRAM:**
[image]

**WHAT I FOUND:**

I got it working but without using the DSP library, which is not a good thing as the DSP is needed here. Somehow the DSP library is adding the two channels together or mixing the two and I have no idea how.

Sample codes that got stereo working:

1.

```
void prcoess_inline_halfSample(int * RxBuff_inline, int * TxBuff_inline, float * inSample_inline_L, float * inSample_inline_R, 
                                   float * outSample_inline_L, float * outSample_inline_R, float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent, 
                                   arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R,
                                   float inputCompensator) {
    
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
    
                TxBuff_inline[i] = RxBuff_inline[i];
            }
    }
    
    void process_inline_CompleteSample(int * RxBuff_inline, int * TxBuff_inline, float * inSample_inline_L, float * inSample_inline_R, 
                                       float * outSample_inline_L, float * outSample_inline_R,float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent, 
                                       arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R, 
                                       float inputCompensator) {
    
    
               for (int i = 2; i < 4; i ++){
                   
                   TxBuff_inline[i] = RxBuff_inline[i];
               }
    
                    
    }
```

2. 

```
void prcoess_inline_halfSample(int * RxBuff_inline, int * TxBuff_inline, float * inSample_inline_L, float * inSample_inline_R, 
                               float * outSample_inline_L, float * outSample_inline_R, float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent, 
                               arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R, 
                               float inputCompensator) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){

              if (i % 2 == 0){ // L Samples

              inSample_inline_L[i] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

            } else if ( i % 2 == 1){ // R Samples

              inSample_inline_R[i-1] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

            }
        }
              //arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_L, inSample_inline_L, outSample_inline_L, 1);
              //arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_R, inSample_inline_R, outSample_inline_R, 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){

               if (i % 2 == 0) { // L Samples

               TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)inSample_inline_L[i];

             } else if ( i % 2 == 1) { // R Samples

               TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)inSample_inline_R[i-1];

             }
        }
}

void process_inline_CompleteSample(int * RxBuff_inline, int * TxBuff_inline, float * inSample_inline_L, float * inSample_inline_R, 
                                   float * outSample_inline_L, float * outSample_inline_R,float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent, 
                                   arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R, 
                                   float inputCompensator) {


           for (int i = 2; i < 4; i ++){

                  if (i % 2 == 0){ // L Samples

                  inSample_inline_L[i-1] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

                } else if ( i % 2 == 1){ // R Samples

                  inSample_inline_R[i-2] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

                }
            }

                 //arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_L, &inSample_inline_L[1], &outSample_inline_L[1], 1);
                 //arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_R, &inSample_inline_R[1], &outSample_inline_R[1], 1);

                 for (int i = 2; i < 4; i ++){

                   if (i % 2 == 0) { // L Samples

                   TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)inSample_inline_L[i-1];

                 } else if ( i % 2 == 1) { // R Samples

                   TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)inSample_inline_R[i-2];

                 }
            }
}
```

What this tells me is that I have my indexing correct, and my L and R channels positioned properly in the buffer to be transmitted to the DAC. Its something up with the DSP library for some reason.

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
void prcoess_inline_halfSample(int * RxBuff_inline, int * TxBuff_inline, float * inSample_inline_L, float * inSample_inline_R,
                               float * outSample_inline_L, float * outSample_inline_R, float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent,
                               arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R,
                               float inputCompensator) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){

              if (i % 2 == 0){ // L Samples

              inSample_inline_L[i] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

            } else if ( i % 2 == 1){ // R Samples

              inSample_inline_R[i-1] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

            }
        }
              arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_L, inSample_inline_L, outSample_inline_L, 1);
              arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_R, inSample_inline_R, outSample_inline_R, 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){

               if (i % 2 == 0) { // L Samples

               TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)outSample_inline_L[i];

             } else if ( i % 2 == 1) { // R Samples

               TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)outSample_inline_R[i-1];

             }
        }
}

void process_inline_CompleteSample(int * RxBuff_inline, int * TxBuff_inline, float * inSample_inline_L, float * inSample_inline_R,
                                   float * outSample_inline_L, float * outSample_inline_R,float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent,
                                   arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R,
                                   float inputCompensator) {


           for (int i = 2; i < 4; i ++){

                  if (i % 2 == 0){ // L Samples

                  inSample_inline_L[i-1] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

                } else if ( i % 2 == 1){ // R Samples

                  inSample_inline_R[i-2] = (float) RxBuff_inline[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;

                }
            }

                 arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_L, &inSample_inline_L[1], &outSample_inline_L[1], 1);
                 arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_R, &inSample_inline_R[1], &outSample_inline_R[1], 1);

                 for (int i = 2; i < 4; i ++){

                   if (i % 2 == 0) { // L Samples

                   TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)outSample_inline_L[i-1];

                 } else if ( i % 2 == 1) { // R Samples

                   TxBuff_inline[i] = (int)outSample_inline_R[i-2];

                 }
            }
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, an oversight on my part.

I was using the same state variables for both channels so thats why it sounded it was mixed together because it was using the old outputs of each channel to calculate a new value for the present channels.